# How to select single row where one field is different? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, common-table-expression, sql-delete

I have a table like below:

```
ID            NAME          SCHOOL          GRADUATIONYEAR           DEGREE                MAJOR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100           Ben         University1          2015             Bachelor of Arts           Major1
100           Ben         University1          2015             Bachelor of Arts           Major2
100           Ben         University2          2017             Master of Science          Major3
```

Since Ben has two records that are from the same university due to double majors (as you can see same School, graduation year, and degree), I only want to pull one of those records rather than both of those records, it doesn't matter which Major I pull, just has to be one instead of both of those records.
So ideally, I'd like for it to be like below:

```
ID            NAME          SCHOOL          GRADUATIONYEAR           DEGREE                MAJOR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100           Ben         University1          2015             Bachelor of Arts           Major1
100           Ben         University2          2017             Master of Science          Major3
```

I have tried to do a delete like below, but this ends up deleting all of the records, is it possible to maybe use CASE in this scenario?

```
DELETE FROM #table1 
WHERE ID = ID AND NAME = NAME AND SCHOOL = SCHOOL AND DEGREE = DEGREE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by name, school, graduationyear, degree 
            order by major
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

When two rows have the same ame, school, graduation year and degree, the query retains the one with the smallest `major`, alphabetically-wise (you can change the `order by` clause of `row_number()` if you want another criteria).

If you wanted a `delete` statement:

```
with cte as (
    select row_number() over(
        partition by name, school, graduationyear, degree 
        order by major
    ) rn
    from mytable 
)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

Comment: Thank you, the row_number() method worked for this scenario, I've not used this method before consistently in the past so will definitely note this.